# how to prevent multiple ..(dots), ee, ++(plus) and --(minus) signs in the p:inputText

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, converters

the **inputText** field is accepting multiple ..(dots), ee, ++(plus), --(minus) signs

even though I am using the converter **type="number"** in the **primefaces 5.2**

```
<p:inputText id="adpNo" type="number" value="#{managedB.adpNumber}"
    validator="#{managedB.fillADPDescription}"
    rendered="#{!managedB.confirm}" disabled="#{utilMB.isEdit}">
</p:inputText>
```

so is there any possible way to make it like p:inputNumber **Primefaces-6.2** but without validator to every Integer field. Thanks

Comment: As far as I can see you are not using any converter. `type="number"` is just a hint for the web browser how to implement the input field. IE11 for example accepts arbitrary text in a field of `type="number"`. Can you use p:inputMask or p:spinner? Why is adding a validator a problem?

Comment: In the fifth chapter of **Definitive Guide to JSF EE 8** it is written as ' ` **<f:convertNumber> uses under the hood java.text.NumberFormat
 The type attribute specifies which instance will be obtained and defaults to number.** ` '  so I used both `<f:convertNumber type="number">` and separately **type="number"** both were working same so I though the attribute is also a converter. and **adpNumber's length** is not fixed that's why I cannot use inputMask.

Comment: `so I used both <f:convertNumber type="number"> and separately type="number"` What's the result of using both? It's not stated in the question..

Comment: Do you want to prevent (+, -,++,--,.,) accepting only (0-9)?

Comment: Yes actually it should work like **p:inputNumber** without validating to every field we are using